# Styling Wpf AlternatingRowBackground on Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to change the AlternatingRowBackground Colour based on a dataTrigger.
I'm getting an error from the IDE and it won't build (see xaml below).

**Error**: Cannot find the Style Property 'AlternatingRowBackground' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow'

**Xaml**

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Beige" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedRowBackgroundBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BondType}" Value="P">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightPink" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your style is targeting the *DataGridRow*, but "AlternatingRowBackground" is a property of *DataGrid*.

So you need a separate style for DataGrid and DataGridRow. Set the AlternatingRowBackground in your DataGrid style:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Beige" />
    ...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridDemoRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
     <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedRowBackgroundBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BondType}" Value="P">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
            </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try and get back to you, makes sense.

Comment: Hi, what I actually want to do is apply the biege on alternating rows, except when the datatrigger is met, at that stage I want lightpink. Is that possible?

Comment: You're saying you want to change the alternatingRowColor for all alternate rows that come after the row where the dataTrigger is met?

Comment: Got it working:
       <Style x:Key="dataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BondType}" Value="P">
                        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightPink" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Yellow" />
            </Style>